# Using ecszap logger with Kubernetes controller-runtime

Tags: go, elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubebuilder, go-zap

I am wrestling with logging in a Kubernetes operator built with:

- KubeBuilderVersion: 3.7.0
- go version: go1.20.1 linux/amd64

Up and until now, for logging purposes, I have made use of the zap logger package ("sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap") and it worked fine.

Lately the need has arisen to make the logging more compatible with Elasticsearch and the [ecs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/go-zap/current/intro.html) logger was suggested. I have tried the example listed [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/go-zap/current/setup.html) in a simple go app and it works fine.

The next step was to substitute the existing zap logging setup inside the operator's code with the ecs one, and that is when progress grinded to a halt.

**The current setup:**

```
"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap"  
ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime"

opts := zap.Options{
    Development: true,
}
opts.BindFlags(flag.CommandLine)

ctrl.SetLogger(zap.New(zap.UseFlagOptions(&opts)))
```

`ctrl.SetLogger` expects a parameter of type `logr.Logger` and that is also exactly what `zap.New(zap.UseFlagOptions(&opts))` returns – so it all works fine and dandy.

*** **setup trying to use the ecszap logger** ***
Using the ecszap example stated [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/go-zap/current/setup.html) again, I end up with the following:

```
ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime"  
ecszap "go.elastic.co/ecszap"  
uzap "go.uber.org/zap"  

encoderConfig := ecszap.NewDefaultEncoderConfig()
core := ecszap.NewCore(encoderConfig, os.Stdout, uzap.DebugLevel)
logger := uzap.New(core, uzap.AddCaller())
```

The `uzap.New(core, uzap.AddCaller())` returns a pointer to the `type Logger struct`. This is (as far as I can see) not what the `ctrl.SetLogger` is expecting (it requires `logr.Logger`) and it then obviously fails for a type mismatch.

[image]

*My question is:*
What is the correct way to get ecszap logger hooked up for usage in an operator?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
    "go.elastic.co/ecszap"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime"
    crzap "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log/zap"
)

func ecsCompatibleEncoderConfig(ecfg *zapcore.EncoderConfig) {
    *ecfg = ecszap.ECSCompatibleEncoderConfig(*ecfg)
}

var ecsWrapCore = zap.WrapCore(func(core zapcore.Core) zapcore.Core {
    return ecszap.WrapCore(core)
})

func setup() {
    opts := crzap.Options{
        EncoderConfigOptions: []crzap.EncoderConfigOption{ecsCompatibleEncoderConfig},
        ZapOpts:              []zap.Option{ecsWrapCore},
    }
    logger := crzap.New(crzap.UseFlagOptions(&opts))
    ctrl.SetLogger(logger)
}
```